# heroku deploy app (toto blog) don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, github, toto

hy i'm trying to deploy a toto blog on heroku system.
this is the guide: [site](http://cloudhead.io/toto)

i have a error when i deploy. can you help me? thanks

```
cristiano@ubuntu64bit1204:~$ git clone git://github.com/cloudhead/dorothy.git myblog
Cloning into 'myblog'...
remote: Counting objects: 202, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (106/106), done.
remote: Total 202 (delta 88), reused 182 (delta 81)
Receiving objects: 100% (202/202), 20.97 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (88/88), done.
cristiano@ubuntu64bit1204:~$ cd myblog/
cristiano@ubuntu64bit1204:~/myblog$ heroku create blogprova
Creating blogprova... done, stack is cedar
http://blogprova.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:blogprova.git
Git remote heroku added
cristiano@ubuntu64bit1204:~/myblog$ git push heroku master 
Counting objects: 202, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (99/99), done.
Writing objects: 100% (202/202), 20.97 KiB, done.
Total 202 (delta 88), reused 202 (delta 88)
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:blogprova.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:blogprova.git'
cristiano@ubuntu64bit1204:~/myblog$
```

Comment: in my .git directory there isn't the .gitignore file.

Answer (score 1):

The project is missing a Gemfile which should specify what gems are required.

More importantly, the last commit to the project was on May 14 2010, so I'd suggest you probably want to find blogging software which is actively maintained, otherwise you're likely to have a hard time.

Comment: I did not realize that the project is no longer maintained. there is a similar system to make a blog?